# make an element with ng-if start hidden (prevent it from showing during page load)

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, ng-show, angular-ng-if

When i want to make something start as hidden with `ng-show` you can just add `class="ng-hide"` so the css will hide the element beforehand. This way an element won't be shown when the page is still loading

I want to do the same thing using `ng-if` but i don't know how to do it

Comment: Maybe using ng-cloak is a solution for you? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Michiel suggested, using the `ngCloak` directive is the solution.
Just add `ng-cloak` to the `class` attribute of the tag you want to keep hidden while your application is loading.

```
<div class="ng-cloak">test</div>
```

For more details: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak